# When to clear the SharedPreferences in the Activity Lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an app and I save some settings in the `onPause()` and load them again in the `onResume()`. That works fine.

But when the app isn't used for a while, I want to start with a clean sheet. But at the moment `onResume()` always restores all the data. So my app is too robust at the moment.

So I would like to clear the `SharedPreferences` at a certain time, but I don't want to loose any data when the screen is rotated or when the user switches between some apps.

How can I know the user is really finished with the app, and doesn't need the `SharedPreferences` anymore? And when in the lifecycle can I clear the `SharedPreferences`?

What is a good practice/pattern for this?

And also I am reading data from a file via the Storage Access Framework (SAF). But when the data is loaded, the `onResume()` kicks in and overwrites all the data! What is a good practice to prevent this?

Comment: "So I would like to clear the SharedPreferences at a certain time" -- why is the data in `SharedPreferences` in the first place? Why are you not just holding onto the data in memory, such as in a `ViewModel`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I use SharedPreferences mainly to store data when the screen is rotated and when coming back from the SAF or when the users switches between apps. Is a ViewModel a better solution? Can you provide me a link where I can find more info about that?

Comment: "I use SharedPreferences mainly to store data when the screen is rotated and when coming back from the SAF or when the users switches between apps" -- that is not what `SharedPreferences` is for. "Is a ViewModel a better solution?" -- IMHO, yes. "Can you provide me a link where I can find more info about that?" -- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel in terms of docs, https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/ in terms of a book.

Comment: In my quest for solving typical Android issues, I took the wrong turn. ViewModel is the way for solving my problems. Thanks.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is fine as a persistent data store, but in your case, you do not seem to want it to be persistent. :-) While there have been a variety of techniques over the years for holding onto data across configuration changes, for modern Jetpack-based app development, `ViewModel` is the leading choice.